# Peking Duck Sauce

Tags: sauce, duck, chinese-cuisine

I have just visited China (Beijing).

There I had Peking Duck which was wonderful. They served it with a sauce - sort of sweet, brown and thick. I was wondering if anyone has a name for this sauce as the people I was with did not know the name.

I really loved this sauce and want to use it with other things - any help on its name would be great!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Traditionally, the sauce combines several ingredients, one of which, as Bart mentioned, is Hoisin sauce. The other ingredients are:

- Sesame Oil
- Hoisin sauce
- Dark sugar or honey
- Water
- Dark soy sauce.
- Cornstarch

You can usually buy this at your local Chinese supermarket, but it's easier and more tasty to make your own.

Answer (score 5):

That must have been [Hoisin sauce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoisin_sauce) or [Sweet bean sauce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_bean_sauce).

Answer (score 4):

This is the sauce I use as an adaptation from years of research:

- 1 T. minced fresh ginger
- 1 T. minced fresh garlic
- 2 T. hoisin sauce* soy,chili,garlic,vinegar BBQ like sauce*
- 2 T. soy sauce
- 1 T. sesame oil
- 1 scallion minced
- 1/2 ts. vinegar
- 1/2 tsp. sugar

Mix well, paint on pancake with scallion brush and add cucumber strip.

Comment: What do the asterisks refer to?

Comment: @Cindy It appears to be the breakdown of what hoisin sauce is

Answer (score 3):

The sauce, easily available in Europe, but not in US or Canada, is Peking Duck Sauce. The one generally cited is Lee Kum Kee Peking Duck Sauce. Do not confuse with Saucy Susan Peking Duck Sauce or other generic Duck Sauces, that are orange or yellow, which are a kind of pineapple sweet and sour sauce. A closer match is Hoisin Sauce, similar but not quite the same if one is very particular; three varieties are available in US (all at Amazon.com); the ones that I have found are Lee Kum Kee/Panda, Koon Chun (very good), and Wok Mei. I have found a source at Amazon.co.uk, but with shipping to the US, it costs about 23 USD. I have to rely on the web, as there are no Chinese groceries within a hundred or more miles of my residence; traveling to which would cost more than the shipping from England. I hope this helps.